How do you instantiate a zeep client outside an asynchronous event loop?
I'm trying to setup zeep to run asynchronously using asyncio, but the wsdl files import other files. Based on the documentation, https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/client.html#the-asyncclient , wsdl documents are loaded using synchronous methods. How can I go about running this code so the zeep client is instantiated outside the asyncio event loop - and still keep it asynchronous.
Current Error: "RuntimeError: WSDL loading is not asynchronous yet. Instantiate the zeep client outside the asyncio event loop."
class ITI38Initiator:
    def __init__(self, cur, response=None, params=None, responder_url=None, responder_hcid=None):
        self.params = params
        print(params)
        self.returntype = self.params["returntype"] if "returntype" in self.params else "ObjectRef"
        print("asking for return type:", self.returntype)
        self.cur = cur
        self.request = response
        self.hcid = "{{redacted-id}}"
        self.receiver_hcid = responder_hcid
        self.url = "https://{{redacted-url}}"
        self.setup_done = False

        if responder_url: # did not receive an xml request, only got initiator url (usually only for testing)
            self.responder_url = responder_url
            self.request = None
        else:
            self.request = response
            root = self.request
            self.responder_url = root.find('.//{*}ReplyTo/{*}Address').text
    
    async def setup(self):
        if not self.setup_done:
            settings = Settings(strict=False, force_https=True)
            ssl_ctx = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.CLIENT_AUTH)
            ssl_ctx.load_cert_chain('cqcert.crt', 'cqkey.key')
            conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl_context=ssl_ctx)
            session = aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=conn)
            self.session = session
            self.history = HistoryPlugin()
            transport = AsyncTransport(session=session, loop=None, cache=None)
            self.client = AsyncClient('wsdls/drive_ITI38_responder.wsdl', settings=settings, transport=transport, plugins=[self.history])
            self.service = self.client.create_service('{urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007}RespondingGatewayQuery_Binding_Soap12',self.responder_url)
            self.setup_done = True

    async def __aenter__(self):
        await self.setup()
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, exc_type, exc, tb):
        await self.session.close()

    async def send_request(self):
        try:
            await self.setup()

Here is the file src.zeep.asyncio.transport.py if helpful.
"""
Adds asyncio support to Zeep. Contains Python 3.5+ only syntax!

"""
import asyncio
import logging

import aiohttp
from requests import Response

from src.zeep.asyncio import bindings
from zeep.exceptions import TransportError
from zeep.transports import Transport
from zeep.utils import get_version
from zeep.wsdl.utils import etree_to_string

try:
    from async_timeout import timeout as aio_timeout  # Python 3.6+
except ImportError:
    from aiohttp import Timeout as aio_timeout  # Python 3.5, aiohttp < 3


__all__ = ["AsyncTransport"]


class AsyncTransport(Transport):
    """Asynchronous Transport class using aiohttp."""

    binding_classes = [bindings.AsyncSoap11Binding, bindings.AsyncSoap12Binding]

    def __init__(
        self,
        loop,
        cache=None,
        timeout=300,
        operation_timeout=None,
        session=None,
        verify_ssl=True,
        proxy=None,
    ):

        self.loop = loop if loop else asyncio.get_event_loop()
        self.cache = cache
        self.load_timeout = timeout
        self.operation_timeout = operation_timeout
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

        self.verify_ssl = verify_ssl
        self.proxy = proxy
        self.session = session or aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=self.loop)
        self._close_session = session is None
        self.session._default_headers[
            "User-Agent"
        ] = "Zeep/%s (www.python-zeep.org)" % (get_version())

    def __del__(self):
        if self._close_session:
            # aiohttp.ClientSession.close() is async,
            # call the underlying sync function instead.
            if self.session.connector is not None:
                self.session.connector.close()

    def _load_remote_data(self, url):
        result = None
        if self.loop.is_running():
            raise RuntimeError(
                "WSDL loading is not asynchronous yet. "
                "Instantiate the zeep client outside the asyncio event loop."
            )

        async def _load_remote_data_async():
            nonlocal result
            with aio_timeout(self.load_timeout):
                response = await self.session.get(url)
                result = await response.read()
                try:
                    response.raise_for_status()
                except aiohttp.ClientError as exc:
                    raise TransportError(
                        message=str(exc), status_code=response.status, content=result
                    ).with_traceback(exc.__traceback__) from exc

        # Block until we have the data
        self.loop.run_until_complete(_load_remote_data_async())
        return result
    
    async def post(self, address, message, headers):
        self.logger.debug("HTTP Post to %s:\n%s", address, message)
        with aio_timeout(self.operation_timeout):
            response = await self.session.post(
                address,
                data=message,
                headers=headers,
                verify_ssl=self.verify_ssl,
                proxy=self.proxy,
            )
            self.logger.debug(
                "HTTP Response from %s (status: %d):\n%s",
                address,
                response.status,
                await response.read(),
            )
            return response

    async def post_xml(self, address, envelope, headers):
        message = etree_to_string(envelope)
        response = await self.post(address, message, headers)
        return await self.new_response(response)

    async def get(self, address, params, headers):
        with aio_timeout(self.operation_timeout):
            response = await self.session.get(
                address,
                params=params,
                headers=headers,
                verify_ssl=self.verify_ssl,
                proxy=self.proxy,
            )

            return await self.new_response(response)

    async def new_response(self, response):
        """Convert an aiohttp.Response object to a requests.Response object"""
        new = Response()
        new._content = await response.read()
        new.status_code = response.status
        new.headers = response.headers
        new.cookies = response.cookies
        new.encoding = response.charset
        return new

